# Copy and Paste Excel selection into Word - data disappears

Tags: object, ms-word, paste

I've been trying to copy & paste a table from Excel into Word, by inserting it as an Excel worksheet object and ensuring I paste as a link, so I retain the formatting from Excel, and allows me to access the specific table easily.

Unfortunately, the excel table disappears apart from the final row of the selection when I paste into Word, and I've no idea how to fix it. The internet isn't giving me any solutions either.

Is this a known issue? Or is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

@Rob, i cannot comment (no privilege) so need to do this via an answer: please check the paragraph setting of the paragraph where you copied the table to and try changing it to anything but not 'fixed height'. Fixed really makes it look as if 1 row is pasted. Let me know if it worked, it did for me.

Comment: Thanks very much @Boeryepes. An easy fix!